# React Express Built app not working in production mode

Tags: reactjs, express, build, create-react-app

I have a Create React App working well in development mode both with
`yarn start`
and
`yarn build > serve -s build`

But when I upload my build folder to my distant server (on Planet Hoster), I get the following errors :

```
GEThttps://www.mysite.fr/static/js/main.f79317f8.js
[HTTP/2 404 Not Found 273ms]

GEThttps://www.mysite.fr/static/css/main.43a07738.css
[HTTP/2 404 Not Found 272ms]
```

What's happening here ? I've been working days and days on it and I still can't find something... Any help will be greatful !

My code to launch my express server :

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
});
```

[EDIT] - Here is my package.json file if it can helps :

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router": "^6.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^2.4.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack": "^5.67.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the build-files created? In your build-folder? You make your build-folder static available on the path `/build`, but the links in your site links to a folder named `static`. Is there some kind of mismatch here?

Comment: That's what I think too.
My build files are located in the  build folder, wich is located at the root "/".

Comment: When, in development mode after serve -s build, I can see that "GET
 http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.f79317f8.js" is working well... But in production, I don't know why but it's not working...

Comment: Do you have a different webpack config for production and dev?

Answer (score 0):

I am coming back to it lately but I finally found the solution.

To achieve it, I ran locally `node app.js` wich is the file that launch my frontend service. I then found in my logs that my script was trying to "modify the headers of my site after they were sent". I fix it and now it works.
My code was probably not that clean.

Still, thank you for your help !